# running sum / cumulative sum with floor and ceiling Py Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm new to spark, and I am trying to calculate a window running sum that is floored by 0 and ceiled by 8

a toy example is given below (note that the actual data is closer to millions of rows):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'ids':    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                    'day':    [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
                    'counts': [-3, 3, -6, 3, 3, 6, -3, -6, 3, 3, 3, -3]})
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
sdf = sdf.orderBy(sdf.ids,sdf.day)
```

This creates the table

```
+----+---+-------+
|aIds|day|eCounts|
+----+---+-------+
|   1|  1|     -3|
|   1|  2|      3|
|   1|  3|     -6|
|   1|  4|      3|
|   2|  1|      3|
|   2|  2|      6|
|   2|  3|     -3|
|   2|  4|     -6|
|   3|  1|      3|
|   3|  2|      3|
|   3|  3|      3|
|   3|  4|     -3|
+----+---+-------+
```

Below is an example of the result of doing a running sum, and **the expected output runSumCap**

```
+----+---+-------+------+---------+
|aIds|day|eCounts|runSum|runSumCap|
+----+---+-------+------+---------+
|   1|  1|     -3|    -3|        0| <-- reset to 0
|   1|  2|      3|     0|        3|
|   1|  3|     -6|    -6|        0| <-- reset to 0
|   1|  4|      3|    -3|        3|
|   2|  1|      3|     3|        3|
|   2|  2|      6|     9|        8| <-- reset to 8
|   2|  3|     -3|     6|        5| 
|   2|  4|     -6|     0|        0| <-- reset to 0
|   3|  1|      3|     3|        3|
|   3|  2|      3|     6|        6|
|   3|  3|      3|     9|        8| <-- reset to 8
|   3|  4|     -3|     6|        5|
+----+---+-------+------+---------+
```

i know i can calculate the running sum as

```
partition = Window.partitionBy('aIds').orderBy('aIds','day').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)`
sdf1 = sdf.withColumn('runSum',F.sum(sdf.eCounts).over(partition))
sdf1.orderBy('aIds','day').show()
```

To achieve the expected I have tried looking into @pandas_udf to modify the sum:

```
@pandas_udf('double', PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def runSumCap(counts):
    #counts columns is passed as a pandas series
    floor = 0
    cap = 8
    runSum = 0
    runSumList = []
    for count in counts.tolist():
      runSum = runSum + count
      if(runSum > cap):
        runSum = 8
      elif(runSum < floor ):
        runSum = 0
      runSumList += [runSum]
    return pd.Series(runSumList)


partition = Window.partitionBy('aIds').orderBy('aIds','day').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
sdf1 = sdf.withColumn('runSum',runSumCap(sdf['counts']).over(partition))
```

However this does not work, and it does not seem like the most efficient way to do this.
How can i make this work? Is there a way to keep it parallel, or do i have to go to pandas dataframes

**EDIT:**
Came with some clarifications about present columns to order the dataset by, and some more insights into what I am trying to achieve

**EDIT2:**
The answer that was provided by @DrChess almost yields the correct result, but the series isn't matching the correct day for some reason:

```
+----+---+-------+------+
|aIds|day|eCounts|runSum|
+----+---+-------+------+
|   1|  1|     -3|     0|
|   1|  2|      3|     0|
|   1|  3|     -6|     3|
|   1|  4|      3|     3|
|   2|  1|      3|     3|
|   2|  2|      6|     8|
|   2|  3|     -3|     0|
|   2|  4|     -6|     5|
|   3|  1|      3|     6|
|   3|  2|      3|     3|
|   3|  3|      3|     8|
|   3|  4|     -3|     5|
+----+---+-------+------+
```

Comment: Do you have a column which allows you to order your dataframe? They are unordered by default (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16207](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16207).

Comment: Yes, i can order on aIds and day. Check the updated question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this by first making an array in each row (using collect_list as a window function) containing the values used to make the running sum up until that point.
I then defined an udf (couldn't make this work with pandas_udf) and this worked.
Below is full reproducible example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import numpy as np

def accumalate(iterable):
    total = 0
    ceil = 8
    floor = 0
    for element in iterable:
        total = total + element
        if (total > ceil):
          total = ceil
        elif (total < floor):
          total = floor
    return total

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'aIds':    [1,  1,  1,  1, 2, 2,  2,  2, 3, 3, 3,  3],
                    'day':    [1,  2,  3,  4, 1, 2,  3,  4, 1, 2, 3,  4],
                    'eCounts': [-3, 3, -6,  3, 3, 6, -3, -6, 3, 3, 3, -3]})

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
sdf = sdf.orderBy(sdf.aIds,sdf.day)

runSumCap = F.udf(accumalate,LongType())
partition = Window.partitionBy('aIds').orderBy('aIds','day').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
sdf1 = sdf.withColumn('splitWindow',F.collect_list(sdf.eCounts).over(partition))
sdf2 = sdf1.withColumn('runSumCap',runSumCap(sdf1.splitWindow))
sdf2.orderBy('aIds','day').show()
```

This yields the expected result:

```
+----+---+-------+--------------+---------+
|aIds|day|eCounts|   splitWindow|runSumCap|
+----+---+-------+--------------+---------+
|   1|  1|     -3|          [-3]|        0|
|   1|  2|      3|       [-3, 3]|        3|
|   1|  3|     -6|   [-3, 3, -6]|        0|
|   1|  4|      3|[-3, 3, -6, 3]|        3|
|   2|  1|      3|           [3]|        3|
|   2|  2|      6|        [3, 6]|        8|
|   2|  3|     -3|    [3, 6, -3]|        5|
|   2|  4|     -6|[3, 6, -3, -6]|        0|
|   3|  1|      3|           [3]|        3|
|   3|  2|      3|        [3, 3]|        6|
|   3|  3|      3|     [3, 3, 3]|        8|
|   3|  4|     -3| [3, 3, 3, -3]|        5|
+----+---+-------+--------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately window functions with `pandas_udf` of type `GROUPED_AGG` do not work with bounded window functions (`.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)`). It currently only works with unbounded windows, namely `.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)`. Additionally the input is a `pandas.Series` but the output should be a constant of the provided type. Therefore you won't be able to achieve partial aggregations with that.

Instead you could use `GROUPED_MAP` `pandas_udf` which works with `df.groupBy().apply()`.
Here some code:

```
@pandas_udf('ids integer, day integer, counts integer, runSum integer', PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def runSumCap(pdf):
    def _apply_on_series(counts):
        floor = 0
        cap = 8
        runSum = 0
        runSumList = []
        for count in counts.tolist():
            runSum = runSum + count
            if(runSum > cap):
                runSum = 8
            elif(runSum < floor ):
                runSum = 0
            runSumList += [runSum]
        return pd.Series(runSumList)
    pdf.sort_values(by=['day'], inplace=True)
    pdf['runSum'] = _apply_on_series(pdf['counts'])
    return pdf


sdf1 = sdf.groupBy('ids').apply(runSumCap)
```

Comment: This solution returns the correct series, but the problem is that it isn't sorted.
I.e id 1 day will be 0, and it's real value will be randomly mapped to day 4

Comment: you can sort also by `id` if needed. You can just do `sdf1.sort('ids', 'day')` at the end.

Comment: I already tried this. It still didn't map result to row, even though you can see that the sequence of the running sum is correct.

Comment: I actually made a minor edit. I forgot to do the `inplace` sort in the pandas df. Which means that the sum was done on an arbitrary order of `day` and `pdf.sort_values(by=['day'])` was just not doing anything.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and assumed it was a mistake. This is what provided the result that i posted in the question. As can be seen the right numbers are calculated, but for some reason they are not insterted into the dataframe in sequential order... Even if i sort on both 
`pdf.sort_values(by=['aIds','day'],inplace =True)`.

If you can provide a working result I will give you the bounty for your help

Comment: that's odd. I copy pasted my code, followed by `sdf1.sort('ids', 'day')` and I got exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: I do that too, but it doesn't work. I will reward you the bounty for your time spent anyway :)